# How to set a default month in an input element?

Tags: html, angular

Say I have an input element like this:

```
<input type="month">
```

How can I set the default value of this input element to the *current* month?

Comment: I notice you keep asking how to use this in an Angular 6 project. If you want that specifically, please edit your question and add the [angular] tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may use some javascript:

```js
const monthControl = document.querySelector('input[type="month"]');
const date= new Date()
const month=("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
const year=date.getFullYear()
monthControl.value = `${year}-${month}`;
```

```html
<input type="month">
```

Comment: I'm using in angular project how can i do this in ts side?

Comment: @PrabodhaRanasinghe There are multiple ways. Simpliest is:
**HTML:**
 <input [value]="month" type="month" (input)="month = $event.target.value">

**TS:**
export class ... {
  month = '';

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    const date = new Date();
    const month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    this.month = `${year}-${month}`;
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

To set the value for the month input (`input[type="month"]`) use only the year and month in the value (`yyyy-MM`), for example:

```
<input type="month" id="txtMonth" value="2018-11" />
```

will display the month as Novermber (in browsers that support month input type, support is patchy).

To populate the field using javascript could do something like:

```js
var txtMonth = document.getElementById('txtMonth');
var date = new Date();
var month = "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1);
txtMonth.value = (date.getFullYear() + "-" + (month.slice(-2)));
```

```html
<input type="month" id="txtMonth" value="2018-11" />
```

Comment: I'm using in angular project how can i do this in ts side?

Comment: This should work for one digit months now. Sorry, I don't know about angular.

Answer (score 2):

You have to construct new Date and query your input, then do something like:

```js
let date = new Date();
let month = `${date.getMonth() + 1}`.padStart(0, 2);
let year = date.getFullYear();
document.getElementById("month").value = `${year}-${month}`
```

```html
<input id="month" type="month" value="2012-3-23">
```

Comment: Thanks, edited, it shoul be working now (added `padStart(2, 0)`).

Comment: i want to use my angular 6  project

Comment: can you help me for using angular 6 proect