# Input type month default value

Tags: html

How to set the default Value of input type month using only HTML??

I tried to set the value like this `<input type="month" value="oct-1982">`
and also like this `<input type="month" value="1982-oct">` but nothing happened

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a default month in an input element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188184/how-to-set-a-default-month-in-an-input-element)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188184/how-to-set-a-default-month-in-an-input-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input id="month" type="month" value="1982-10">
```

But you should take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53188466/12102286

Comment: Already took a look but they use in answers Javascript and I want to do it in html only

Comment: but they explain that the value has to be in a numeric type

Answer (score 0):

The format of `value` is YYYY-MM (both numerical), so use:

```
<input type="month" value="1982-10">
```

Comment: Fantastic! Please accept the answer or upvote it if it's helped :)